# Change a date string in Javascript preserving the timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have the following date string: `Sat, 23 May 2015 05:49:45 GMT`. I need to get this date and add 1 second to it, and end up with `Sat, 23 May 2015 05:49:46 GMT`. It's important that:

- The date string stays the same, with the same timezone. This means that if I do `var d = Date.parse('Sat, 23 May 2015 05:49:45 GMT')` and then add 1 second to `d` (easy, `d += 1000`) and reconvert it back to a string, I end up with `Sat May 23 2015 14:49:46 GMT+0800 (AWST)` which is *not* what I want.
- (Obviously) It needs to be a "proper" adding of a second, keeping into account the change of hour/date/etc.

What's the best way to go about this? I don't really want to do it purely with String manipulation, because it would be kind of ridiculous.

Comment: Please confirm that you see "Sat May 23 2015 14:49:46 GMT+0800 (AWST)".   Given your timezone the time part should return as 13:00 rather than 14:00.  So I'm wondering if that is a typo since I can't reproduce it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> This means that if I do `var d = Date.parse('Sat, 23 May 2015 05:49:45 GMT')` and then...

...and then it'll fail on some browser somewhere, because the [**only** date/time format that the JavaScript `Date` object is required to parse](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) by the specification is completely different from that. If JavaScript parses it in your environment, you have absolutely no guarantee JavaScript will parse it in another environment.

Instead, **you** need to parse it, which is fairly easy, and then form a new string:

- Use a regular expression to capture the day, month, year, and time from the string; you'll need a lookup table giving month name => month number. Glancing at that string, the rex would be something along the lines of `/^..., (\d{1,2}) ([^ ]+) (\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/`. Then the day number is in capture group 1, the month name in capture group 2, etc.
- Create a `Date` instance via `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))`.
- Add a second to it: `dt.setUTCSeconds(dt.getUTCSeconds() + 1)` (`Date` will handle the rollover).
- Produce a string in the desired format. You'll need a lookup table giving you day number => day name. When getting the parts of the date/time, use the `getUTCXyz` methods, not the `getXyz` methods.

*(Or you can use a library like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) to do all that for you. [I'm not affiliated with them in any way.])*

Comment: I didnt mention that the date string comes from a Date HTTP header. So parsing is quote safe, right?

Comment: @Merc: It's not in the specification, so I wouldn't rely on it until/unless you've tested it on all browsers and in all locales where you intend to rely on it. Me? I'd just do the parsing, it's a trivial amount of code.

Comment: Is there a library out there that will parse the Date header for me? Surely that must follow a precise standard...

Comment: @Merc: See the last paragraph/sentence of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

### The Easy Answer

The simplest solution is just to use "Date.toUTCString()" rather than "Date.toString()" method.

**Example:**

```
var d = new Date('Sat, 23 May 2015 05:49:45 GMT');
d.setUTCSeconds( d.getUTCSeconds() + 1 );
console.info( d.toUTCString() );
```

**Output:**

- Sat, 23 May 2015 05:49:46 GMT  *( for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE11 )*
- Sat, 23 May 2015 05:49:46 UTC  *( for IE<11 )*

In contrast, using toString() will return the date with timezone:

- Sat May 23 2015 13:49:46 GMT+0800 (AWST)  *( depends on locale )*

---

**Additional Details:**

In practice, most browsers can parse an [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) date-time which are seen in headers, RSS feeds, etc. The format looks like:

```
var d = Date('Sat, 23 May 2015 05:49:45 GMT');
```

Even IE5 can parse this date correctly. The only caveat applies to timezones. It understands named timezones like GMT and EST (USA) but might have trouble with AWST (Australia). Yet, using a time offset, rather than a name, will avoid this problem:

```
var d = Date('Sat, 23 May 2015 13:49:45 +0800' );  // +8 AWST
```

Yet, this is not an issue for OP as he is pulling the date from the http header, which will be in GMT ... so no timezones to worry about.

To adjust the date one might be tempted to add milliseconds directly to the date value like d += 1000.  Yet, that can have unexpected results. It's safer to use the Date UTC methods so that date calculations use normalized values, e.g.,

```
d.setUTCSeconds( d.getUTCSeconds() + 1 );
```

And multiple changes may be made simultaneously like:

```
d.setUTCHours( 
    d.getUTCHours() + hours, 
    d.getUTCMinutes() + minutes,
    d.getUTCSeconds() + seconds 
);
```

Reference: [MDN Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

**Try it with your browser:**

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="toString"></div>
<div id="toUTCString"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = new Date( 'Sat, 23 May 2015 05:49:45 GMT' );
d.setUTCSeconds( d.getUTCSeconds() + 1 );
document.getElementById('toString').innerHTML = 'toString = ' + d.toString();
document.getElementById('toUTCString').innerHTML = 'toUTCString = ' + d.toUTCString();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```